Cannot connect to PostgreSQL database server using PGAdmin
I've been using SQL Server and Oracle for almost twenty years but I'm now trying out PostgreSQL which I've hosted on AWS.
I set the database to be publicly accessible and then I downloaded PGAdmin and tried to connect to my server. I used the endpoint from AWS and my username and password for the database and set the Maintenance Database to the name of my PostgreSQL database.
I get a timeout error as shown below:
enter image description here
I'm obviously missing something, can someone with more experience of this please help.
I've rechecked all the settings, I've opened port 5432 and ran it again but I still get the same error

The DB name in the screenshot is TestDB, the role name Admin- mixed case names. I always use legal, lower-case identifiers in Postgres, so I never have to double-quote. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860 But you may have to. Or lower-case entries in pgAdmin if you created the DB (and username) without double-quotes. (Though the error msg for a wrong DB name is "connection failed: FATAL: database "TestDB" does not exist" - but AWS may hide this, not sure.)

hi, maybe your aws database doesnt have the security group configured to allow postgres port 5432 to be open to connections?
a timeout in AWS is a firewall not open to connections on that port, you should check your database security group

First, confirm that the DNS Name resolves to a public IP address (eg if you ping it, does it show a public IP address?). If so, check that your Security Group permits inbound access on port 5432 from 0.0.0.0/0 (which can be tightened later). Next, confirm that the database was launched in a public subnet (defined has having a Route Table pointing to an Internet Gateway). When connecting, if the error comes back immediately, then the networking is fine and it's just the database that is refusing the connection. If it takes longer, then it's a connectivity problem.

have you tried to check if the socket/port is open/listening and accepting connection? you can try telnet postgre-address-here 5432 or curl -vvk postgre-address-here:5432. If the output is connection refused or just connecting ... (then stuck), then probably its network/port/address binding problem instead of db configuration problem

I managed to resolve the issue by adding new rules for inbound and outbound to go to my IP address and then saving.
